# I want to pass email and password directly after clicked login button

Tags: java, android

I want to pass username and password directly to another activity to login automatically after I clicked login button.But,my code can pass only after one time clicked login button.I used Sharedpreferences method to save username and password.I have mainactivity.java and loginactivtiy.java.If I clicked login button,pass username and password to mainactivity to login automatically in webview.How can I do that?Please help me.Sorry for my bad english sentences.

**Here is Piece of my code Mainactivity.java**

```
/* get email and password from memory for auto login*/

                Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

                String Username = b.getString("Username");
                String Password = b.getString("Password");
                Log.d("Username Check", "this username is " + Username);
                Log.d("Passowrd Check", "this password is " + Password);

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    sb.append("document.getElementById('signin-email').value = '" + Username + "';");
                    sb.append("document.getElementById('signin-password').value = '" + Password + "';");
                    sb.append("document.getElementById('login_frm_id').submit();");

                    sb.append("})()");

                    view.loadUrl("javascript:" + sb.toString());

            }
```

**Here is Loginactivity.java**

```
  final  String username=  mEmailView.getText().toString();
    final  String password=  mPasswordView.getText().toString();


    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.v("Username", "Username is " + username);
                /*encrypt password*/
                try {

                    Key key = AESHelper.generateKey();
                    byte[] encrypted = AESHelper.encrypt(password.getBytes(), key); //暗号化された
                    byte[] encrypt = AESHelper.decrypt(encrypted, key); //復号化した
                    String decrypted = new String(encrypt); //文字列に戻した

                    Log.v("EncryptDecrypt", "Encoded String " + encrypt);
                    Log.v("EncryptDecrypt", "Dncoded String " + decrypted);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                savePreferences("storedName", mEmailView.getText().toString());
                savePreferences("storedPass", mPasswordView.getText().toString());


                Intent i =new Intent (LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("flag", "add");
                startActivity(i);

                finish();



            if (username!=null && password!=null) {
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                Intent intent= new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                b.putString("Username", username);
                b.putString("Password", password);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);

            }else{

                Intent b =new Intent (LoginActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(b);

            }


        }

    });
```

**saving username and password**

```
 /*Saving username and password using sharedpreference*/
private void loadSavedPreferences() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedName",mEmailView.getText().toString());
    String pass = sharedPreferences.getString("storedPass", mPasswordView.getText().toString());

    mEmailView.setText(name);
    mPasswordView.setText(pass);

}

private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: did you tried the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this thing by maintaining a boolean in preference. When user login for first time set its value true. in your main activity at onCreate method check this value . if it is true just pass a intent to your next activity. else ask user to login.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically wrap up the `mEmailSignInButton`'s onClick code in a separate function and call it in the `Loginactivity`'s onCreate callback. For instance:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* .... */
    loadSavedPreferences();

    checkCredentials(username, password);
}
```

and

```
private void loadSavedPreferences() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedName",mEmailView.getText().toString());
    String pass = sharedPreferences.getString("storedPass", mPasswordView.getText().toString());

    mEmailView.setText(name);
    mPasswordView.setText(pass);
    username = name;
    password = pass;

}
```